# Macbook Pro track pad isn't responding. I want to install a magic mouse via Bluetooth but can't tab over to select it with the keyboad

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, magic-trackpad

I can't select the Magic Mouse that appears in the Bluetooth screen as I don't have a pointing device. In Windows, you'd just tab over to the open screen, select the device with arrow keys and press enter. I'm stuck.

Comment: Plug in a cheap wired mouse, do what you need.

Comment: Why not using Voice Control? (And enable this with Siri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mouse Keys to accomplish this.

If you have a TouchID sensor, press it five times to active, otherwise, press <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd>.  You can then use your keyboard to navigate your mouse.

See the Apple Support Document [Control the pointer using Mouse Keys](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-the-pointer-using-mouse-keys-mh27469/mac) on Mac

[image]